# The date of birth can only be edited once

Tags: magento2, customer-account

[image]

I want the Date of Birth to be edited only once then disable it.
Same as photo.
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides disabling the **Dob** field from frontend, we also have to disable it in the backend to prevent customers from bypassing the `disable` feature from frontend.

Let's create a custom module. Assume we set the vendor as **Vendor** and the module name is **Customer**.

Step 1: Create `registration.php` file:
File path: `app/code/Vendor/Customer/registration.php`

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_Customer', __DIR__);
```

Step 2: Create the `module.xml` file:
File path: `app/code/Vendor/Customer/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Customer">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create the `di.xml` file:
File path: `app/code/Vendor/Customer/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob">
        <plugin name="DisableChangeDobInCaseItAlreadyHasValue" type="Magetu\Catalog\Plugin\DisableChangeDobInCaseItAlreadyHasValue"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Step 4: Create the `DisableChangeDobInCaseItAlreadyHasValue.php` plugin file:
File path: `app/code/Vendor/Customer/Plugin/DisableChangeDobInCaseItAlreadyHasValue.php`

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Customer\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class DisableChangeDobInCaseItAlreadyHasValue
{
    /**
     * Add disabled attribute to Dob field in case Customer already set the Dob value.
     *
     * @param Dob $subject
     * @param string $result
     * @return string
     */
    public function afterGetHtmlExtraParams(Dob $subject, string $result): string
    {
        try {
            if ($subject->getRequest()->getActionName() !== 'create' && $subject->getData('value')) {
                $result .= ' disabled';
            }
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            // do nothing
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Step 5: Create the `events.xml` file:
File path: `app/code/Vendor/Customer/etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_save_before">
        <observer name="RevertDobInCaseItAlreadyHasValue" instance="Vendor\Customer\Observer\RevertDobInCaseItAlreadyHasValue" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Step 6: Create the `RevertDobInCaseItAlreadyHasValue.php` observer file:
File path: `app/code/Vendor/Customer/Observer/RevertDobInCaseItAlreadyHasValue.php`

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Customer\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

/**
 *  Revert Dob value in case Customer already set the Dob value before.
 */
class RevertDobInCaseItAlreadyHasValue implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Revert Dob value in case Customer already set the Dob value before.
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var  $customer \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer */
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

        if ($customer->getOrigData('dob')
            && $customer->getData('dob') !== $customer->getOrigData('dob')
        ) {
            $customer->setData('dob', $customer->getOrigData('dob'));
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Step 7: Deploy the changes:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

If you are in the [**production**](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cli/set-mode.html?lang=en#:%7E:text=be%20var.-,Display%20the%20current%20mode,-The%20easiest%20way) mode, you'll need to deploy static content.

You're done.

Comment: thanks so much. i solved the problem

Comment: Great answer. Haven't tested it but looks like a top end answer to me!

Comment: Yeah, it works as expected.